# need a help json with php

Tags: php, json

i'm using json files with php, and i wanna add like Unlike buttons on my site

data in json file

```
[{"uid":"10", "name":"john"}, {"uid":"11", "name":"alejandro"}]
```

json file is : Likes

my general code is :

```
$fileName = 'path/to/Likes.json';
$fopen    = fopen($fileName, 'a+')
$getFile  = file_get_contents($fileName);
$json_arr = json_decode($getFile, true);

foreach($json_arr as $key => $value)
{
   if($value['name'] == 'john')
   {
      echo 'Unlike';
   }
   else
   {
      echo 'Like';
   }
}
```

**but the results is Unlike Like together**

please help me, thanks

Comment: you have two values, and are outputting two values. you don't get buttons because you're not outputting any html to define those buttons.

Comment: Why are you calling `fopen()`? You're not doing anything with that file handle.

Comment: please i want if john was liked that post for example give him Unlike button  but if does not give him Like button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just for adding the button

```
    foreach($json_arr as $key => $value)
    {
       if($value['name'] == 'john')
       {
          echo '<button type="button">Unlike</button>';
       }
       else
       {
          echo '<button type="button">Unlike</button>';
       }
    }
```

But once you added the button ...

Comment: yes thanks, but i wanna chek if user was but like show him Unlike